# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно сказать: *имущество амортизирует* или *амортизируется?*

Comment: на мой взгляд заголовок этого вопроса крайне неинформативен. я считаю, что его необходимо изменить так, чтобы в нём отражалась суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

1. АММОРТИЗАЦИЯ [от лат. amortisation - погашение] Постепенное снижение ценности основных фондов (сооружений, машин, оборудования и т.п.)вследствие их износа;  Амортизация дома.
2. АМОРТИЗАЦИЯ [от франц. amortir - ослаблять, смягчать].Смягчение действия толчков, ударов с помощью амортизаторов.

АМОРТИЗИРОВАТЬ,  св. и нсв. (что).Произвести/производить амортизацию во втором значении.  Амортизировать удары. Шлем амортизирует при аварии.

Также есть слово "амортизироваться": удар амортизируется.

ВЫВОД

Правильно: происходит амортизация имущества. Глаголы амортизировать/амортизироваться в этом значении не употребляются.

Comment: В бухгалтерии употребляется фраза "Имущество амортизируется", сделали замечание - правильно говорить "имущество амортизирует". Пока нет ясности.

Comment: Тогда берем словарь Ожегова, там еще указывается значение глагола "амортизировать" как произвести/производить амортизацию (экономический термин). Тогда верно "имущество амортизируется" в значении "снижается его ценность". Но только не "амортизирует" - это переходный глагол, амортизировать имущество может только себя, то есть амортизироваться.

Comment: Пример использования термина "имущество амортизируется" http://www.garant.ru/hotlaw/minfin/443768/. Но чаще говорят: имущество подлежит амортизации, амортизируемое имущество, амортизация рассчитывается, начисляется,  но даже словосочетание "амортизировать имущество" в бухгалтерских текстах не встречается.